# VueJS linked inputs

Tags: validation, data-binding, vue.js

I would like to link multiple inputs via VueJS and compute the values.

The inputs are to track vehicle mileage, and therefore any given day's value, cannot be less than the previous day's value.

[image: Linked Inputs]

So far I have come up with the following (it's very convoluted and I know it can be tidied up but I'll improve on that later). It doesn't work, as you can't change any value apart from *Monday Start*.

https://jsfiddle.net/mstnorris/qbgtpm34/1/

**HTML**

```
<table id="app" class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Day</th>
        <th>Start</th>
        <th>End</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Mon</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="mon_start" number id="mon_start" placeholder="Monday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="mon_end" number id="mon_end" placeholder="Monday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Tue</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="tue_start" number id="tue_start" placeholder="Tuesday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="tue_end" number id="tue_end" placeholder="Tuesday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Wed</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="wed_start" number id="wed_start" placeholder="Wednesday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="wed_end" number id="wed_end" placeholder="Wednesday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Thu</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="thu_start" number id="thu_start" placeholder="Thursday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="thu_end" number id="thu_end" placeholder="Thursday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Fri</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="fri_start" number id="fri_start" placeholder="Friday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="fri_end" number id="fri_end" placeholder="Friday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sat</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sat_start" number id="sat_start" placeholder="Saturday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sat_end" number id="sat_end" placeholder="Saturday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">Sun</th>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sun_start" number id="sun_start" placeholder="Sunday Start Mileage">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" v-model="sun_end" number id="sun_end" placeholder="Sunday End Mileage">
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**VueJS**

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        mon_start: '',
        mon_end: '',
        tue_start: '',
        tue_end: '',
        wed_start: '',
        wed_end: '',
        thu_start: '',
        thu_end: '',
        fri_start: '',
        fri_end: '',
        sat_start: '',
        sat_end: '',
        sun_start: '',
        sun_end: ''
    },
    computed: {
        mon_end: function() {
            return this.mon_start
        },
        tue_start: function () {
            return this.mon_end
        },
        tue_end: function() {
            return this.tue_start
        },
        wed_start: function () {
            return this.tue_end
        },
        wed_end: function() {
            return this.wed_start
        },
        thu_start: function () {
            return this.wed_end
        },
        thu_end: function() {
            return this.thu_start
        },
        fri_start: function () {
            return this.thu_end
        },
        fri_end: function() {
            return this.fri_start
        },
        sat_start: function () {
            return this.fri_end
        },
        sat_end: function() {
            return this.sat_start
        },
        sun_start: function () {
            return this.sat_end
        },
        sun_end: function() {
            return this.sun_start
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

**Why does this not work so far?**

You are mixing data property names with computed properties, so the value will be read from the computed property (`get`) and it will try to write it back to the same computed property, which wont work since you haven't assigned a `setter`.

Also, always showing the value of `mon_start` in `mon_end` etc. will not allow you to show the updated value of `mon_end` in `mon_end`.

**Computed: Getters and Setters**

What you actually want is a custom action to happen when a new value is set (e.g. `mon_start` is set to 2, thus all other fields should be set to `2`).

Now we could just say: If `mon_start` is updated, update `mon_end`. If `mon_end` is updated, update `tue_start`. And so on.

This can be achieved using [**computed setters**](http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter):

```
    mon_start_model: {
        get: function() {
              return this.mon_start
            },
        set: function(val) {
            this.mon_start = val
            this.mon_end_model = this.mon_start
        }
    },
```

I've simplified the example a little bit (using only Monday and Tuesday).

**Avoiding confusing the user**

As an extra condition for user-friendliness, you probably only want the next value to update if the next value is smaller or equal to the previous value.

Eg. `mon_start` is `1` at the beginning, then you update `mon_end` to `5`, then you update `mon_start` to `3`. You probably want `mon_end` to keep the value `5`, right?

```
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        mon_start: 0,
        mon_end: 0,
        tue_start: 0,
        tue_end: 0,
    },
    computed: {
        mon_start_model: {
            get: function() {
                  return this.mon_start
                },
            set: function(val) {
                this.mon_start = val
                this.mon_end_model = Math.max(this.mon_end, this.mon_start)
            }
        },
        mon_end_model: {
            get: function() {
                return this.mon_end
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.mon_end = val
                this.tue_start_model = Math.max(this.tue_start, this.mon_end)
            }
        },
        tue_start_model: {
            get: function () {
                return this.tue_start
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.tue_start = val
                this.tue_end_model = Math.max(this.tue_end, this.tue_start)
            }
        },
        tue_end_model: {
            get: function() {
                return this.tue_end
            },
            set: function(val) {
                this.tue_end = val
            }
        }
    }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbgtpm34/5/